# Using reflection for reduce database queries

Tags: java, database, reflection, refactoring

Background:
I am currently working on a java project with two other people, and each of us are reading from an Oracle database and wrapping the returned rows in our own unique object. What stinks is that it requires 3 separate-but-nearly-identical methods: open the connection, create/execute the prepared statement, iterate over the results, return a list of the results. What we'd like to do is have just one method which would encapsulate that functionality, but we have the issue of specifying the unique data object.

So, my question is would reflection be reasonable in this situation? My understanding is that it should be avoided because it tends to be a red flag for poor design, but using it would greatly reduce the number of methods that would be created initially as well as further down the line. I am aware that there could be an if/else chain to determine which object it is, i.e.

```
if(objectTypeStr.equals("Foo")){
   //insert into list of type Foo
}else if(objectTypeStr.equals("Bar")){
   //insert into list of type Bar (etc.)...
```

However I feel that this would become a gross method to deal with, making reflection a clean way of dealing with this.

I am open to any other ideas to solve this, thank you for reading through my question

Comment: This sounds like you have a slight code smell that could be solved by smarter design, but you're trying to get rid of code lines with reflection and possibly end up with a horrible design. Your description is quite vague though, could you give some more info? However, don't go down the "I want one method to do everything" route, that's usually the sign of a lazy and inexperienced programmer. Also, using `compareTo` to test for equality is a red flag in my eyes, you're not a very experienced Java programmer are you? Maybe from a C background, since in Java we would use `equals()`.

Comment: How about passing a data object factory to the method that does the identical operation?

Comment: If you use something like JPA, mapping between the database and your database tables and relationships is easy. You don't have to write the mapping code at all. JPA also gives you connection pooling and transactions, most of which you'd have to build yourself with your approach. I'm having a hard time seeing your approach becoming anything but a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Kayaman: This is more of a brainstorming question, I suppose. I will say that this method would only be used for this singular purpose (wrap rows returned from the database in a pojo and insert into a list)--not sure if that constitutes a "do everything method".
 
And my apologies about using the compareTo()--I'm fresh out of college and I guess I just never knew any better. Though now that you mention it, it really doesn't make a lot of sense to use that outside of sorting--live and learn.

Comment: @Holger & Baldy: I will look into both of these recommendations, and thank you both for responding

Comment: @schil227 What do you mean by "unique object"?

Comment: @Chedy2149 an object which is completely different between the three of us, such that none of us share the same one; e.g. {Banana, Phone, Box}

Comment: @schil227 Why not creating an abstraction of the unique objects since they follow the same implementation pattern (1-create connection 2-...) and leverage polymorphism?

Comment: @Chedy2149 +1 That actually makes a lot of sense--I was thinking of some way to implement polymorphism without passing around with the ResultSet, abstraction seems like the obvious choice. Thank you, you should add that as an answer

Comment: There isn't enough code to see how well it would work, but could you use Generics?